Spring native tomcat does not run
I'm trying to build and run my Spring Boot 3.3.5 project using Spring Native.
Dependencies:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

Plugins:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-buildpackless-tiny</builder>
            <buildpacks>
                <buildpack>paketobuildpacks/oracle</buildpack>
                <buildpack>paketobuildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
            </buildpacks>
        </image>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Configuration:
server:
  port: 8080
  shutdown: graceful
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: servlet

Application Class:
@SpringBootApplication
public class ChatbotMemberEventWorkerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChatbotMemberEventWorkerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Dockerfile:
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-community:latest as builder

COPY . /artifact
WORKDIR /artifact

RUN microdnf -y install wget unzip zip findutils tar maven
RUN mvn -Pnative native:compile

FROM container-registry.oracle.com/os/oraclelinux:9-slim

EXPOSE 8080

COPY --from=builder /artifact/target/chatbot-member-event-worker ./chatbot-member-event-worker

ENTRYPOINT ["./chatbot-member-event-worker --spring.profiles.active=local"]

Problem:
When I run the application, the application starts but immediately exits. It looks like the web server isn't actually running.
Log Output:
INFO 39222 --- [chatbot-member-event-worker] .g.c.ChatbotMemberEventWorkerApplication : Starting AOT-processed ChatbotMemberEventWorkerApplication...
INFO 39222 --- [chatbot-member-event-worker] .g.c.ChatbotMemberEventWorkerApplication : The following 1 profile is active: "local"
Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.






)

Any insights into why this is happening or how I can keep the server running? Thanks!

It turns out it is related with
spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap dependency, when I remove that, I have successfully
